# Frequency of every Word in a String

Tags: c

I am writing some code which finds the frequency of every word in a given string using the strtok() and the strstr() functions. I don't know what is the problem with my code as no output is being displayed on the screen. Can anyone help me?I am new to C programming.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(){

  char s[2222];
  gets(s);
  char *t,*y=s;
  int count=0;
  t=strtok(s," ,.");

  while(t!=NULL)
  {
    count=0;
    while(y=strstr(y,t))
    {
      y++;
      count++;
    }
    printf("%s appeared %d times.\n",t,count);
    t=strtok(NULL," ,.");
  }
}
```

Comment: `strtok()` modifies its argument. You are using pointers `y` and `t` that point somewhere inside the same (changing) object.

Comment: If you're learning to program, please forget you ever heard of `gets()`. It can never be used safely, and has been deprecated for some time. Most compilers will produce code that prints a warning message whenever your program runs. At some point in the future, this function will be removed altogether from stdio.h.

Comment: You fail to take into account that the input string being pointed to by `y` is being broken into tokens. Make a copy of the input first. Also, you didn't reset `y` for the next token. Hence the program crash.

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane it worked by pointing `y` to the copy of the string and resetting `y`at the end.

Comment: One problem is `strstr` is looking for substrings, not for words. `"a marble"`: 1. `"a"` is the first word `strtok` will find. 2. `"strstr"` will find `"a"` in `"marble"` as the second word.

Comment: I was going to point out it is not a very good algorithm anyway. My corrected version when given the input "two one two" reports "two appeared 2 times. one appeared 1 times. two appeared 2 times."

Comment: @WeatherVane I have also made another algorithm to show the output without any repetition which worked perfectly. I was just wondering if it could've worked with `strstr` and `strtok` functions.

Comment: As ZDF wrote, it is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot use `strstr` to search for words: the number of occurrence of `"is"` in `"is this a test?"` is two, not one.
2. You cannot use `strtok` two times; first time to search for first occurrence and second time for subsequent occurrences, instead of `strstr`: `strtok` is using a static variable (see the note in this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx)).

**[EDIT]**

A begginner solution ([run it](http://ideone.com/bEUXAl)):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAXWORD 32
typedef struct
{
  char word[MAXWORD];
  int count;
} word_and_count_t;

#define MAXWORDCOUNT 1024
word_and_count_t table[MAXWORDCOUNT];

int table_size;

word_and_count_t* find( const char* word ) // range checking ignored
{
  int i;

  for ( i = 0; i < table_size; ++i )
    if ( !strcmp( table[i].word, word ) )
      return table + i;

  strcpy( table[i].word, word );
  table[i].count = 0;

  ++table_size;

  return table + i;
}

void display()
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < table_size; ++i )
    printf( "%s - %d\n", table[i].word, table[i].count );
}

int main()
{
  //
  char s[] = "The greatness of a man is not in how much wealth he acquires, but in his integrity and his ability to affect those around him positively.";

  //
  for ( char* word = strtok( s, " ,." ); word; word = strtok( 0, " ,." ) )
    find( word )->count++;

  //
  display();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think the main problem is that you don't provide a sentence to get the words.

```
char s[2222] = "Enter here the sentence you want to check.";
```

Comment: 6th line: `gets(s);`.

Comment: Not even with the obsolete `get(s);`?

Comment: @PrakharSaxena please find a more modern text book.